# Некорректный вывод даты в цикле

Tags: javascript

Задача стоит в нахождении каждой даты пятницы 13-числа

Ошибка в том что при выводе идёт одна и та же дата(8/13/1999), вместо того чтобы вывести 8/13/1999, 10/13/2000

```
moment = require( 'moment' );
moment.locale('ru');
let arrYears = [1999,2000]
let arr = []
let date13

    for(let j = 0; j < arrYears.length; j++){
        let year = arrYears[j]
        for(let mount = 0; mount < 12; mount++){
          let d = new Date(year, mount, 13);
          if (d.getDay() == 5) {
              arr.push(d);
              date13 = arr.toLocaleString()
              date13 = moment(date13, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ').format( 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
              console.log(date13)
          }
        }
      }
```

т.е вместо чтого чтобы вывести 8/13/1999, 10/13/2000

выводит 8/13/1999

Comment: какую дату выводит-то?

Comment: 8/13/1999 - два раза вместо 8/13/1999, 10/13/2000

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы приводите весь массив `arr` к строке, а не работаете с элементами, ведь у вас уже есть `let d`. В любом случае функция moment явно к такому не готова, её содержание из приведенного кода неизвестно.

Comment: console.log(moment(d).format( 'MM/DD/YYYY')); //и уберите вообще переменную date13

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177061/konst дал хорошую подсказку что привело к верному ответу на вопрос

```
moment = require( 'moment' );
  moment.locale('USA');
  let arrYears = []
  let date13
  let arr = []

    for(let j = 0; j < arrYears.length; j++){
        let year = arrYears[j]
        for(let mount = 0; mount < 12; mount++){
          let d13 = new Date(year, mount, 13);
          if (d13.getDay() == 5) {
              arr.push(moment(d13).format( 'M/DD/YYYY'))
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(arr.join(' '))
      return(arr.join(' '))
```

но переменную arr я уже использовал для другой цели